# Problem with populating field that uses jQuery inputmask

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-inputmask

I am using a jQuery inputmask on the following form element (named 'Last_Reviewed_On') of my ASP.NET web application:

```
                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-floating">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control d-flex" id="Last_Reviewed_On" name="Last_Reviewed_On">
                            <label for="Last_Reviewed_On">Last Reviewed</label>
                        </div>
```

The initialization of the inputmask in my Javascript is as follows:

```
 $('#Last_Reviewed_On').inputmask({ alias: "datetime", inputFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy" });
```

So, the form element works very well.  It shows a 'mm/dd/yyyy' mask, and there's a calendar icon for the user to select a date as well.  I can fetch the value entered by the user correctly.  The problem is when I try to set the value of the form element using data from an existing record.  I am using an `$.ajax` call to a webhandler to fetch a record, which I then wish to display in the form.  I am using the following code to populate the 'Last_Reviewed_On' form element:
`$('#Last_Reviewed_On').val(data.Last_Reviewed_On);`

Nothing appears in the form element though.  All I see is the input mask.  I know the data is there, since I used `console.log` to inspect the value.
Any idea why this isn't working?  I use inputmask for other fields without issue, so I'm stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Quite sure for a label you use text() and not val() as you have.

Comment: It isn't a label, it's a text input that uses inputmask for ensuring proper data entry.  I tried using ```text``` and that didn't work either.

Comment: ah, I read "for" as meaning id - my bad. You are setting the textbox by id - my mistake. Ok, then what jQuery input mask library? If you add which one your using (cdn), I am willing to try and play to see why one can't set the text box.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this was to switch to a bootstrap datepicker control, using this code:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Last_Reviewed_On" name="Last_Reviewed_On" />
    <label for="Last_Reviewed_On">Last Reviewed On</label>
</div>
```

and the following jQuery to initialize:

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
});
```

It works well and prevents entry of invalid dates.